# Is there way that I can align below?

Tags: css, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Eyh.png)

I respect your help, I do not have an experience React and Java Script.
I am studying by my self so far so sorry for basic(?) question.
I have been struggling with this problem.

In the screenshot,

Distance, Time and Pace are center.
I want to make Distance: Time: Pace: left, and then align input boxes indivisually like below

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11TGP.png)]

```
// to use jsx 
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import './styles.css'


// to reactcomponent(by function)

function Home() {
   const [message, setMessage]=useState([]);
   useEffect(()=>{
     fetch("/test/hello")
         .then((response)=>{
           return response.json();
         })
         .then((data)=>{
             setMessage(data);
         });
   },[]);
   return (
      <div>
         <div className="logo-container">
         <Logo />
         <h1 style={{ fontSize: '40px', color: '#333333' }}>Pace Calculator</h1>
         </div>

         <div className="input-container">
      <div className="input-group">
        <label className="label">
          Distance<span className="colon">:</span>
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          : 
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
          /km
        </label>
      </div>

      <div className="input-group">
        <label className="label">
          Time<span className="colon">:</span>
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="hr" />
          : 
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          : 
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
        </label>
      </div>

      <div className="input-group">
        <label className="label">
          Pace<span className="colon">:</span>
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          : 
          <input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
          /km
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button className="calculate-button">Calculate</button>

    </div>
   );
 }
 
export default Home;
```

```
/* styles.css */

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #333; /* Add a solid border with the color of your choice */
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px; /* Add padding for better visual appearance */
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.input-group {
  display: flex; /* Display the input groups in a row */
  align-items: center; /* Align items vertically in the input groups */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.label {
  font-size: 30px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
}


.input-field {
  width: 40px; 
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.calculate-button {
  margin-top: 30px; 
  background-color: #808080; 
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  font-size: 30px; 
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the button */
}
.calculate-button:hover {
  background-color: #1b1b1b; /* Darker green color on hover */
}
```

Comment: A `table` or CSS-Grid/Sub-grid would probably be ideal here. Otherwise, fixed widths. There is no way to align "columns" in separate flexbox containers,

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in the HTML structure to wrap the input group title (e.g."Distance" and the first colon) in their own span together with `display: contents` to allow the children to inherit the CSS-Grid layout when using `subgrid`.

**This method require some *very* new CSS properties and frankly a re-organisation of the whole HTML structure and layout would be better** but this does seem to achieve what you are looking for.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.input-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 40px .75em 40px .75em 40px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  /* Add a solid border with the color of your choice */
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* Add padding for better visual appearance */
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  display: contents;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.label {
  font-size: 30px;
  /* Adjust the font size as needed */
  display: contents;
}

.colon {
  grid-column: 1;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.input-field {
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">
      <span class="colon">Distance:</span>
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
      :
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
      /km
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">
      <span class="colon">Time:</span>
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="hr" />
      :
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
      :
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">
      <span class="colon">Pace:</span>
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
      :
      <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
      /km
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the simplest approach can be to set width to the labels(Distance/Time/Pace) also making sure that they are left aligned, rest all other inputs fields will also be aligned as per your requirements.

**FYI:** the JSX elements was not well structured, so i have refactored it should be 1 parent node and only 2 direct child nodes, plz refer the code snippet below Thanks

[image]

```css
.input-field-label {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.input-field-wrapper {
  .input-field {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="input-container">
      <!-- Parent -->
      <div class="input-group">
        <!-- child 1 -->
        <label class="input-field-label"> Distance: </label>
        <!-- child 2 -->
        <span class="input-field-wrapper">
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          :
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
          /km
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-field-label"> Time: </label>

        <span class="input-field-wrapper">
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="hr" />
          :
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          :
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-field-label">Pace:</label>
        <span class="input-field-wrapper">
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="min" />
          :
          <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="sec" />
          /km
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```